# Weird MySQL query that's wracking my brain

Tags: mysql

Okay, I have two tables. One is `events` and the other is `occurs`. The `event` table is basic, the event, it's ID, its description, etc... The `occurs` table is linked to the `events` table using the event ID; its basically a table of times for the event. For instance, if an event occurs every Tuesday, then an event will have an occurrence every Tuesday night in the database.

By default, the a row in the `events` table does not have any timestamps in it, those are all in the `occurs` table. However, for some reason or another I have the need to get the results of the `events` table and also have a timestamp on it. So what I would like to do is use a query to the `events` table, linked to a single row in the `occurs` table. The part I am stuck on is which occurrence to get.

If the event has any occurrence after the current time, I would like to simply get the next upcoming occurrence. However, if it is a past event, with no upcoming occurrence, I would like to get the most recent occurrence (last).

Anyone got any tips or hints on how to get this done?

Comment: Would love it if you could go to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and build out a test db for us to use.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql?rq=1) about nested SQL queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is JOIN the `occurs` table twice, one unconditional and get the max timestamp and one conditional on timestamp > current time and get the min timestamp. Then if the second one is not null use that otherwise use the first one.

This is NOT REAL CODE, just a quick pseuodcode example:

```
SELECT events.eventid,
  events.description,
  CASE WHEN MIN(ob.timestamp) IN NOT NULL THEN MIN(ob.timestamp) ELSE MAX(oa.timestamp) END AS timestamp
FROM events
  LEFT JOIN occurs oa ON events.id=oa.eventid
  LEFT JOIN occurs ob ON events.id=ob.eventid and ob.timestamp>Now()
GROUP BY events.eventid, events.description
```

Comment: Hmm... could you add an example of this?

Comment: see my answer below. You can test at sqlfiddle.com: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06b2aa/1/0

Comment: @Jason: I am more used to MS SQL Server than MySQL so I can't do it on the fly, sorry. If you still need it by Friday I will have time to do it then.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
create table events (id integer, descr varchar(20));
create table occurs (event_id integer, occur_date timestamp);
insert into events values (1, 'EV1');
insert into events values (2, 'EV2');
insert into occurs values (1, str_to_date('2016-03-09 05:40:00 AM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));
insert into occurs values (1, str_to_date('2016-03-09 08:40:00 AM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));
insert into occurs values (1, str_to_date('2016-03-09 11:40:00 AM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));
insert into occurs values (1, str_to_date('2016-03-09 05:40:00 PM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));
insert into occurs values (1, str_to_date('2016-03-09 06:40:00 PM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));
insert into occurs values (1, str_to_date('2016-03-09 07:40:00 PM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));
insert into occurs values (1, str_to_date('2016-03-09 09:40:00 PM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));
insert into occurs values (1, str_to_date('2016-03-09 10:40:00 PM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));
insert into occurs values (2, str_to_date('2016-03-09 05:34:00 AM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));
insert into occurs values (2, str_to_date('2016-03-09 08:34:00 AM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));
insert into occurs values (2, str_to_date('2016-03-09 11:34:00 AM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));
insert into occurs values (2, str_to_date('2016-03-09 02:34:00 PM','%Y-%m-%d %r'));

#solution
select e.id, e.descr, coalesce(min(o2.occur_date),max(o.occur_date)) as time_stamp, now()
from events e left join occurs o on e.id = o.event_id
left join occurs o2 on e.id = o2.event_id and o2.occur_date > now()
group by e.id, e.descr
```